# Solving for $x$ in the system $A =G \cos x -F \sin(y-x)$, $B = -F\cos(y-x)-G\sin x$

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

> If I have the two following equations:
>
> $$\begin{align}
> A &=\phantom{-}G \cos x -F \sin(y-x) \\
> B &= -F\cos(y-x)-G\sin x 
> \end{align}$$
>
> and $A$, $B$, $F$, $G$, and $y$ are all known, what is the easiest method of calculating $x$?

For context:  I need to be able to solve this equation for $x$ to determine the angular position of a pedal on a bike using accelerometer data. I will be coding the solution in arduino code.

To be totally honest, I am not the greatest at maths and have no real starting point. I looked into Cramer's rule but that will not work for this application.

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Write 
$$\sin(y-x)=\frac{G\cos(x)-A}{F}$$ and
$$\cos(y-x)=\frac{-B-G\sin(x)}{F}$$
Squaring both equations and adding both we get

$$1=\left(\frac{G\cos(x)-A}{F}\right)^2+\left(\frac{-B-G\sin(x)}{F}\right)^2$$
Can you proceed?
Now we get
$$F^2=A^2+B^2+G^2-2GA\cos(x)+2BG\sin(x)$$

Comment: thank you for your help! Unfortunately I was not able to complete the steps myself, If  its not too much hassle can you give me more steps?

Comment: Now use the substitution $$\sin(x)=\frac{2t}{1+t^2},\cos(x)=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$ the so-called Weierstrass substitution

Comment: It will be a quadratic equation .

Comment: Thanks again! however I think this maths is beyond my level, though I really appreciate you helping me get a start!

Comment: Should i solve your equation for you?

Comment: that would be fantastic! sorry for not be able to

Comment: You will get two solutions

Comment: $$t_1=-{\frac {2\,BG-\sqrt {-{A}^{4}-2\,{A}^{2}{B}^{2}+2\,{A}^{2}{F}^{2}+2\,
{A}^{2}{G}^{2}-{B}^{4}+2\,{B}^{2}{F}^{2}+2\,{B}^{2}{G}^{2}-{F}^{4}+2\,
{F}^{2}{G}^{2}-{G}^{4}}}{{A}^{2}+2\,GA+{B}^{2}-{F}^{2}+{G}^{2}}}
$$

Comment: $$t_1=-{\frac {2\,BG+\sqrt {-{A}^{4}-2\,{A}^{2}{B}^{2}+2\,{A}^{2}{F}^{2}+2\,
{A}^{2}{G}^{2}-{B}^{4}+2\,{B}^{2}{F}^{2}+2\,{B}^{2}{G}^{2}-{F}^{4}+2\,
{F}^{2}{G}^{2}-{G}^{4}}}{{A}^{2}+2\,GA+{B}^{2}-{F}^{2}+{G}^{2}}}
$$

Comment: I hope, you will be happy now!

Comment: ah okay so I sub t the value found for t into x = asin(2t/(1+t^2)) for x?

Comment: Yes, this is right, from where does this problem come?

Comment: To find the pedal angle i am using an accelerometer, during one revolution the accelerator will produce instantaneous values in the X and Y direction (A and B in the formula). The total force acting on the accelerometer is the combination of the centerifugal force and gravitational force (F and G in the formula)! F can be found by the rpm and radius cyling motion and G is alway 9.81. If the angle of crank is know we can solve for x (which you kindly solved for me!)